# How to show a PopUp with a label message,GridView and Button?

Tags: c#

I want to show a pop-up in which I need to display a message and grid view which contains two columns. One is checkbox and two is filename. By default all the checkboxes should be checked.
After that I need to display a button in that pop-up. Once the pop-up prompted the user should be able to deselect checkboxes. when the user clicks on button,I need to get all the filenames for which the checkbox is checked. This pop-up should return these filenames which have the checkbox checked.

I tried all the ways. some how I am failing to display it in pop-up. I am able to display it in div.

can some one help on this?

I need it in asp.net

Comment: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET ?

Comment: Did you try jQuery UI modal popup?

Comment: tried but failed to execute. Can someone post an example atleast?